# Fatal Error using grunt-aws-s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gruntjs

I'm probably not configuring this right and for the life of me I just can't figure out where the mistake is. I'm using the [grunt-aws-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-aws-s3) package and when I run it I get this error:

[image]

Obviously some string or array somewhere is not being assigned a value that is expected. The question is which one? As a test, I tried to send the contents of one folder on my E: drive (specifically, E:\quest) to my S3 bucket. The grunt file is also located on the E: drive (at E:\s3) and looks like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({
        aws: grunt.file.readJSON('grunt-aws.json'),
        aws_s3:{
            options: {
                debug:true,
                region:'us-west-1',
                access:'bucket-owner-full-control',
                uploadConcurrency: 5, // 5 simultaneous uploads
                downloadConcurrency: 5, // 5 simultaneous downloads
                differential: true, // Only uploads the files that have changed
                gzipRename: 'ext' // when uploading a gz file, keep the original extension
            },
            backup:{
                options: {
                    accessKeyId: '<%= aws.backup.key %>',
                    secretAccessKey: '<%= aws.backup.secret %>',
                    bucket: '<%= aws.backup.bucket %>'
                },
                files: [
                    {'action':'upload', expand:true, cwd:'../quest', src:['**'], dest:'/quest'}
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-aws-s3');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'aws_s3:backup'
    ]);
};
```

I think it is the configuration because I don't get any S3 errors, and if it were communicating I would think I would have communication error of some sort. If someone could point out where I'm holding it wrong I'd be very appreciative.

Alternately, if anyone has a good, working AWS S3 module for Grunt I'd appreciate knowing the name of it.

Comment: ../quest are you sure about it?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the files are there. FWIW, I tried the direct path 'E:/quest/' and got the same result.

Comment: and what is `aws-sdk` version used?

Comment: That is a good question, and I don't know what version that package uses. There were no external dependencies listed on the NPM page, so I just installed that package, set the config in the grunt file, and tried to run it. If I need an external SDK installed that might explain the error.

Comment: I installed the latest version of `aws-sdk` and still have the same error. And, I checked and `grunt-aws-s3` comes with the requisite sdk.

Comment: On what line is the error happening? I only see `.length` referenced here: https://github.com/MathieuLoutre/grunt-aws-s3/blob/bda1f3f61d18f77f34a6a7fb6012982a2902f71c/tasks/aws_s3.js#L226 Would be odd for `uploads` to be `null`.

Comment: Actually, the stack trace might help too.

Comment: Sadly, there isn't a stack trace. I'll update the question with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is as simple as having the wrong version number in the package.json file. For some strange reason I was referencing "~0.2" when I should have been referencing the most current version "~0.14". I told you I was holding it wrong. Now I know where. Thanks to all that tried to figure it out.